# angularJS carry selected value to next page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

Hey I have two JSP pages that are step(s) 1 & 2 of a form. On step 1 I am displaying certain category options a user can choose from. In order for the user to get to step 2, they must click one of the category options and upon going to step 2, I am trying to display the name of the category that they clicked on. I know with ng-model, one can bind it to an input and display what is interacted in that input but for some reason it is not working if I bind the ng-model to a "p" or "span". I am new to AngularJs so please bare any rookie mistakes.

step_one.jsp

```
<div class="col-sm-6" ng-click="setStep(2)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span>
       <p ng-model="category">Cutlery &#38; Service</p>
</div>
```

step_two.jsp

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="requestCategory">Category:</label>
            <p id="requestCategory" ng-model="category">{{category}}</p>
        </div>
```

JS to switch steps:

```
 $scope.setStep = function (step){
        $scope.step = step;
    };

    $scope.isStepSet = function(step){
        return ($scope.step === step) ;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you intermingling server vs client side development?

You have 2 JSPs, which I'm assuming each load AngularJS?  The majority of Angular apps work with a single page (i.e. one JSP) and dynamically load/show different content (i.e. through angular views).  Single page applications (SPAs) maintain state within a single page and Angular provides constructs to do this with $scope (you can also use localStorage to do this).

It looks like you're transitioning from a classic web/server-side development model to a client-side model. To do what you want to do above, you can keep everything in 1 JSP and use the following code:

HTML

```
<div ng-show="isStepSet(1)" ng-init="setStep(1)" class="col-sm-6" ng-click="setStep(2)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span>
    <p ng-model="category">Cutlery &#38; Service</p>
</div>

<div ng-show="isStepSet(2)" class="col-md-12">
    <label for="requestCategory">Category:</label>
    <p id="requestCategory" ng-model="category">{{category}}</p>
</div>
```